# Read <input> in a functional (stateless) component

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, redux

I have two components: one container component and one presentational component.

The container fetches all the information and actions needed to display a Post using the presentational component. On the presentational component I have a way where I can toggle between presenting the information and editing it. When I edit and submit the data about the post, I want to read the values from all the different inputs I have so I can dispatch an action.

However, the inputs are **not** inside a `<form id='theForm' onSubmit={onHandleSubmit}>` tag. Instead, all the `<input>` and `<button type='submit'>` that are outside the `<form>` have a `form='theForm'` attribute.

I thought that I could have many `<input>` outside the form, but as long as the `form` attribute pointed towards the corresponding `<form>`, I could read it values using the event that `handleOnSubmit (e) {...}` recieves. However, I haven't figured out how to do that.

How can I read the values of the inputs on my `handleOnSubmit` function? Or this a completely wrong idea I should abandon?

```
// PostSummaryContainer.js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { loadPost, editPost, editPostCancel, editPostSubmit } from '../../actions/posts'

import PostSummaryView from '../../views/details/summary'

class PostSummaryContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleOnCancel = this.handleOnCancel.bind(this)
    this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleOnEdit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.editPost()
  }

  handleOnCancel (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.editPostCancel()
  }

  handleOnSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // How do I read the input values? <--------------------
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    const {
      id,
      loadPost
    } = this.props

    loadPost(id)
  }

  render () {
    const {
      post,
      isLoading,
      isEditing
    } = this.props

    const viewProps = {
      bacon,
      isLoading,
      isEditing,
      handleOnEdit: this.handleOnEdit,
      handleOnCancel: this.handleOnCancel,
      handleOnSubmit: this.handleOnSubmit
    }

    return (
      <PostSummaryView {...viewProps} />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {
    params: {
      id
    }
  } = ownProps

  const post = state.entities.post[id]

  const {
    isLoading,
    isEditing
  } = state.posts

  return {
    id,
    post,
    isLoading,
    isEditing
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loadPost, editPost, editPostCancel, editPostSubmit }
)(PostSummaryContainer)
```

On my presentation component:

```
// PostSummmaryView.js
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'

function PostSummaryView (props) {
  const {
    post,
    isLoading,
    isEditing,
    handleOnEdit,
    handleOnCancel,
    handleOnSubmit
  } = props

  const formId = 'editPostForm'

  return (
    isLoading
      ? <div>Loading...</div>
      : <div className='row'>
          {isEditing && <form id={formId} onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}><input type='text' name='name' /></form>}

          <div className='col-md-6'>
            <img src={post.media.url} className='img-responsive' />
            {isEditing && <input type='file' name='media' form={formId}/>}
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-6'>

            <h1>{post.name}</h1>
            <p>
              {moment(post.publicationDate).format('dddd, MMMM Do')}
            </p>

            <hr />

            <p className='text-left'>
              {post.description || 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit...'}
            </p>

            {isEditing
              ? <div>
                  <button className='btn btn-lg btn-default' onClick={handleOnCancel}>Cancel</button>
                  <button type='submit' className='btn btn-lg btn-default' form={formId}>Submit</button>
                </div>
              : <button className='btn btn-lg btn-default' onClick={handleOnEdit}>Edit</button>
            }

          </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default PostSummaryView
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I'm still new to React/Redux, so take this answer with a *big* grain of salt.

I think your approach is *slightly* off, in that you shouldn't need to go around and gather any data from inputs when submitting (whether inside or outside the `<form>`). Your state should always be in one central, consolidated place.

Given you provide a Cancel option, keeping the Post data updated during an Edit in a separate part of the state is more elegant (IMHO) than directly modifying the "source" Post data.

You could create a reducer for the Edit Post form that keeps key/value pairs for the input fields.

When a user starts editing, you could clone the original Post data into this new part of the state specific to the Edit form. As the user changes the inputs, you could dispatch actions saying "hey, form field X was changed to value Y", which could be reduced onto the state *without* modifying the original Post data.
Pseudo-code example of the state object in this flow:

```
{
    // The actual Post data
    post: {
        media: {...},
        title: "My First Post",
        publicationDate: 1455768160589,
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"                  
    },

    // The temporary Post data in the Edit form
    postForm: {
        media: {...},
        title: "My Turbo-Charged First Post",
        publicationDate: 1455769951276,
        description: "Updated description yadda blah"                  
    }
}
```

Then, in your presentation component, you could drive the input values off `postForm` instead of `post`.

Each input would be given a change handler function so updates are immediately reflected in the state (or *not* reflected, depending on your validation logic/reducers).
i.e.:

```js
// In your actions associated with `Post`
// ------------------------------------------
function updateForm(field, value) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_FORM,
        field,
        value
    }
}

// In your container
// ------------------------------------------
handleOnEdit(event) {
    postActions.updateForm(event.target.name, event.target.value)
}

// In your reducer
// ------------------------------------------
switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FORM:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.field]: action.value
        }
}

// In your presentational component's render() method
// ------------------------------------------
const {postForm, handleOnEdit} = this.props
const descriptionMarkup = (
    isEditing
    ? <input type='text' name='description' value={postForm.description} onChange={handleOnEdit} />
    : (post.description || 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit...')
)
// ...
<p className='text-left'>
    {descriptionMarkup}
</p>
```

If you follow this pattern (and again, not sure it's "right"!), submitting the form becomes as simple as doing something with your state's `postForm` object. That object should always reflect the latest-and-greatest form input values.

Canceling the form becomes as simple as setting the `postForm` part of the state tree to `{}`. The original Post data remains the same.

Hope this helps jog some ideas...

Some other examples/approaches you could try:

- [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) by erikras
- [stateless-form-examples](https://github.com/nackjicholson/stateless-form-examples) by nackjicholson
- [redux-form-example](https://react.rocks/example/redux-form-example)

Comment: Ah. This seems like a good idea to try. Tomorrow I'll check it out and report back with how it went. Thanks!

Comment: I tried implementing this or using redux-form. I had a hard time with redux-form's documentation so I gave up on it. And I will explore your idea for a future project. In the end I ended up refactoring my code from functional components to class X extends Component and reading the inputs became and easier task. I also got rid of the <form> and the form attributes.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: Great, sounds like a good learning experience — any chance you could update your question with your refactored solution?

Comment: I ended up using `redux-form` and it works great! Initially I found the documentation very confusing and lacking good examples, but after revisiting it a couple of days later, it made sense. So that's what I ended up doing! Thanks for your ideas and suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: I won't say this as the solution but rather a workaround to OP's problem. Technically, you could use `document.querySelector` to get the values of input fields and pass it on to your `submit` handler but that would defeat the purpose of having a library to take care it for you so I'd suggest you rather stick with stateful components since it does hold some form of state on your app. So, not quite the answer you're looking for but in this case using stateful component would make more sense.